# Not sure how to describe this line of code

Tags: java

It works fine but I'm just not sure how it works, could anyone explain it? Thanks

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) { 
  return b==0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b); 
}
```

Comment: is the syntax or the algorithm what you don't understand?

Comment: Google for "Euclidean Algorithm"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm

Comment: its the algorithm i don't understand

Answer (score 7):

You have a ternary operator (`bool ? x : y`). Such an operator will evaluate the statement before the question mark. If that evaluates to `true`, x will be chosen, y otherwise.

This means its logic is equivalent to this:

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b)
{ 
  if (b == 0)
      return a;
  else
      return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Next, `a % b` calculates the modulo of the two numbers, which is the remainder of the integer division `a / b`. Eg: `7 % 2` results in `1` and `14 % 5` yields `4`.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

Syntax:

`return b==0? a :gcd(b, a%b)`

means

```
if(b==0)   
  return a; 
else   
  return gcd(b, a%b);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a **[recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)** static method, which calculated gcd of two numbers.

Consider this invocation of this method -

```
int gcd = gcd(12, 6);
```

Your method body becomes equivalent to -

```
return 6==0 ? 12 : gcd(6, 12 % 6);
```

since 6 is not equal to zero, `gcd` gets called again. This time, it's something like this -

```
return 0 == 0 ? 6 : gcd(6, 0 % 6);
```

and since 0 == 0 is true, 6 gets returned, which is the [**greatest common divisor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between 12 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

It is the implementation of the euclids algorithm to find the greatest divisor. It uses a recursion.